# Xamarin xlsx как прочитать

Tags: c#, xamarin, nuget, xlsx, epplus

Существует библиотека EPPlus (OfficeOpenXml), которая позволяет читать эти файлы, но Xamarin её не поддерживает. Существуют ли какие либо аналоги для чтения этого формата?

К слову, примерно так выглядит чтение ячеек в EPPlus

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(name)))
{
    var myWorksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); //select sheet here
    var totalRows = myWorksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
    var totalColumns = myWorksheet.Dimension.End.Column;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(); //this is your your data
    for (int rowNum = 1; rowNum <= totalRows; rowNum++) //selet starting row here
    {
        var row = myWorksheet.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, totalColumns].Select(c => c.Value == null ? string.Empty : c.Value.ToString());
        sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", row));
        sb.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону базовых компонентов от Майкрософт (Open XML SDK).   
Просто первый пример на его основе: (Open-Xml-Sdk), документации я не нашел, но если судить по описанию, то вам можно брать примеры от родного Open XML SDK.
https://github.com/wotzisname/open-xml-sdk-xamarin  
Вы уверенны, что хотите обрабатывать файлы на телефоне, а не на сервере?

Comment: @Dev да, задача открывать файл на телефоне